# Azure Portal error using VM Images

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, portal

I'm trying to create a classic vm from a vm image. See screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKRHt.png)
I always get an error (a raining cloud...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create Ds1_V2 VM on Azure Portal.

[image]

According to your error, it seems that your issue is a browser compatibility issues. If possible, you could try to a Ds1_V2 VM by using Powershell.  If you could create it, maybe you could try to use the following ways.

1.Try to reset your IE

2.Try to use Microsoft Edge or Chrome.

3.Try to test in other PC.

Comment: OK. Now it works. But I havent reset my browser. It just works today...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use size v2 with a classic VM.  Try using a regular d2 in classic or v2 in ARM.